# custom drop down menu javascript issues in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am learning WordPress and have a query with some custom jQuery javascript I use for a drop down menu.

The javascript is used to put a slight delay on the drop down hiding after mouseoff of either the parent link or the drop down etc.

The javascript works great in normal html but not in the basic WordPress theme I am building. I tried following the no-conflict $j advice but not sure if I did that right.

One issue is that the drop down menu stays persistent on mouseover of the parent link - it does not hide after the 2 seconds specified in the javascript.

I think it may be related to the line "var menu_timer;" at the top of the custom.js file but it could be that the code is not working above or below the line:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
```

The custom.js javascript file is enqueued in functions.php and showing in the footer as expected. All other javascripts in the custom.js file are working, just not the drop down menu code which is shown below in the order (eg above and below the doc ready line) that the programmer gave it to me

```
var menu_timer;

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    submenuPersistent();
    $(window).resize(function() { 
        submenuPersistent();
    });

});

// no conflict
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

// menu
 function submenuPersistent() {
    if($j(window).width() >= 651) {
        $j('#nav > ul > li .drop').hide();
        $j('#nav > ul > li').off('mouseenter');
        $j('#nav > ul > li').off('mouseleave');
        $j('#nav > ul > li').mouseenter(function() {
            if($j(this).find('.drop').length != 0){
                clearTimeout(menu_timer);
                $j('#nav > ul > li').not(this).find('.drop').hide(200);
                $j(this).find('.drop').show(200);
            }

        });
        $j('#nav > ul > li').mouseleave(function() { //edit: missed the $j originally
            if($j(this).find('.drop').length != 0){
                element= $j(this); //edit: missed the $j originally
                menu_timer= setTimeout(function() {
                    element.find('.drop').hide(200);
                },1500);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        clearTimeout(menu_timer);
        $j('#nav > ul > li').off('mouseenter');
        $j('#nav > ul > li').off('mouseleave');
        $j('#nav > ul > li .drop').show();
    }
 }
```

The site is still very much in development so I cannot show a live page at the moment unfortunately.

I would greatly appreciate any help from an experienced javascript / WordPress user.

Any ideas?

EDIT: This has been resolved. I missed a couple of $j conversions

Comment: Did you check the browser console for error messages?

Comment: Hi Chris, Thank you for the assist. I did check the debugger beforehand in web developer tools (firefox) but it didn't seem to show an error (I don't know how to use that debugger section). However, after your comment I went back to web developer tools and looked in the console section - that showed an undefined $ in a couple of spots - notably I missed the $j in: `$('#nav > ul > li').mouseleave(function() {` and `element= $(this);`. Its working as expected now, thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah, that was my initial guess as well; should've mentioned it right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help from Chris G. He prompted me to check for javascript errors. I went into web developer tools in the console section and it showed an undefined $ in a couple of spots - notably I missed the $j in: $('#nav > ul > li').mouseleave(function() { and element= $(this);. Its working as expected now.